# Ajax return no result set when special characters exists in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

When i tried to get data from a UTF-8 encoded database with ajax in json-format and the data contains special characters like Ä,Ö,Ü,ä,ö,ü,... then the result set is empty!

```
$('.club-details').click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var data = {
        gid: $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().data('gid'),
        club_number: $(this).parent().parent().data('club')
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: TRANSFER_CALLS_URI,
        data: 'key=getClubDetails&data=' + JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var html = "";
            html += "<table>";
            html += "   <tr>";
            html += "       <td>Name kurz</td>";
            html += "       <td>" + response[0].name_short + "</td>";
            html += "   </tr>";
            html += "   <tr>";
            html += "       <td>Schießstätte</td>";
            html += "       <td>" + response[0].location + "</td>";
            html += "   </tr>";
            html += "   <tr>";
            html += "       <td>Telefon</td>";
            html += "       <td>" + response[0].phone + "</td>";
            html += "   </tr>";
            html += "</table>";
            element.unbind('click').popover({
                content: html,
                title: 'Vereinsinformation',
                html: true,
                placement: 'bottom'
            }).popover('show');
        },
        error: function() {
            $.error('Ajax');
        }
    });
});
```

Data records without german special characters will be successfully received and displayed.

Comment: Have you tried to use `utf8_encode` on each value before converting your data with `json_encode`?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

You should check the encoding of your browser, your server-side language, your database connection, your database, your table, your column. Make sure all of this is UTF-8.

Comment: All of your points are UTF-8 but it doesn't work :( Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Not really, but you need to isolate the bug. Open a database client or command line and do a select on the exact data that is not displaying, see if you can display it here. If nothing is wrong here, try to do the simplest query with your server-side query and display the data. If still nothing wrong, copy/paste your German text into your javascript file and try working with it directly, without ajax query to the server. You get the point, keep splitting the process in smaller parts if needed, the scope is to vague for now, you won't get precise help here.